# Lenovo Y500 can't set brightness

Tags: brightness, lenovo

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a Lenovo Y500 laptop (2012), video card is Nvidia 650M (no integrated graphics), I'm using driver 310.19. The problem is that I can't adjust brightness at all. If I press the relevant media keys, the indicator in ubuntu works correctly but the brightness is not changed.

So far I've tried the following:

Editing xorg.conf in this way:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Adding the options acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor to the grub boot options

Setting brightness from the terminal and using xbacklight. The values of /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness can be changed as well but the brightness remains the same.

Do you have any other hints?

**Solution**

It is possible to enable the backlight by installing the [nvidiabl](https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl) module. First of all install git and dkms:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git dkms
```

Download the code on your machine and compile the package:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl.git
$ cd nvidiabl
$ sudo make dkms-install
```

Now the module should be installed. To activate the nvidiabl module you should issue the command:

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidiabl
```

Now the directory /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight/ should be present. In order to manually change the brightness you have to write in the brightness file:

```
$ sudo su
# echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backligh/brightness
```

You can substitute 100 with any value up to 127. In my case not the complete range of backlight are supported. You can tune the brightness calibration by varying the min and max parameters (you will still have to write values in brightness up to 127):

```
$ sudo modprobe -r nvidiabl
$ sudo modprobe nvidiabl max=100000 min=10
```

You can load the module at startup by adding nvidiabl (with or without max and min parameters) to the file /etc/modules, but I still haven't figured out how to properly add hotkeys.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @function It's 12.10 (I've also updated the question)

Comment: Have you tried [`nvidiabl`](https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl)? I *need* this on my HP Elitebook in combination with a 313.x Nvidia driver for stable brightness controls.

Comment: @gertvdijk Thank you for the suggestion! I installed nvidia 313 driver and nvidiabl (I loaded with modprobe -r nvidiabl) but still not working

Comment: @pygabriel `modprobe -r` **removes** modules, use `modprobe` without the `-r` option instead and try to add it to `/etc/modules` (just `nvidiabl` on a single line) and reboot your system. Additionally: *what* are you trying in order to change the brightness? Are you using the interfaces in `/sys`, using the hotkeys, ...?

Comment: You've probably done this, but just in case, after updating the grub options, did you remember to `sudo update-grub`? Silly suggestion but worth a punt...

Comment: @gertvdijk I retried without -r but it doesn't seem to have any effect, I change the brightness using the hotkeys, it would be the same as using the /sys interfaces (the brightness file is updated as well). Thank you also for the other information regarding the plain nvidia driver that's very interesting.
Sparhawk I've edited directly the booting line from grub, but still thank you for commenting (details are important)

Comment: @gertvdijk I realized that the nvidiabl module added another sys (nvidia_backlight) interface. By acting on this interface the backlight of the monitor works! Thank you so much

Comment: @pygabriel Good. Now just a way to fix the hotkeys to actually change the brightness. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: @pygabriel Another user made it a nice question: [How are key codes mapped to the appropriate action?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243751/how-are-key-codes-mapped-to-the-appropriate-action). It's still a bug report though, it should work out of the box on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I installed Xubuntu 12.10 on my new Lenovo Y500 and also could not adjust brightness, it was at at maximum and could not be controlled. 
Get installed and used graphics driver:

`lshw -c video`

Gave me:

```
configuration: drigver=nouveau latency=0
```

- changing the value in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` does not change brightness
- booting with `acpi_backlight=vendor` does not change brightness
- `etpci -s 00:01.0 F4.B=XX (XX = 00 to ff)` does not change brightness

For the moment I solved this by installing the nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

This gives you the terminal command:

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

Go to: 
`DFP-0-(LGD), Tab: Color Correction`

Here you can set the brightness.

Comment: No. This is not changing the brightness of the backlight. It will change the output of colours and will result in a lower contrast and will not help in reducing power usage.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to grub:

```
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

Comment: Did you try this and did it work?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but yes it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am using xbacklight
you can install it with: sudo apt-get install xbacklight
xbacklight use-help for saver as used, is very simple to use, you can assign any key convinacion
ami I worked until you install some nvidia driver
you can install it manually by downloading the driver from the nvidia official website as follows:
ctrl + alt + f1
LightDM stop sudo service
sudo chmod + x NVIDIA.run
sudo. / NVIDIA.run

if there is some error with the nouveau driver, select that whether or accept
restart the computer and re-run the NVIDIA.run

or repositories THROUGH
for ubuntu 13.04 or 12.10:
sudo apt-add-repository ppa: xorg-edgers/ppa
for ubuntu 12.04:
sudo apt-add-repository ppa: ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this is helpful to anyone at all, but I've come across this post several times looking for help with my Y500.

I'm running mint cinnamon 17 and I have the GT 750M, with the NVIDIA drivers.  All I needed to do was install xbacklight and set my keyboard bindings for the function keys to `xbacklight -inc 10` and `xbacklight -dec 10`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the brightness problem on a Lenovo Y500 you should to do the following:

**1.** In the file "**/etc/default/grub**" you need to change following string:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

**2.** **Reboot** your laptop!

**3.** Now you can change the brightness of display with following command (**for example we want to set 30% of brightness**):

> echo 30 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness

**4.** If you want configure the brightness automatically during booting OS you need the following. After selecting a suitable brightness, add the following command to **/etc/rc.local** (for example if you have chose 30% of brightness):

> echo 30 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness

I have tested this on my Lapton Y500, GeForce GT 750M (Ubuntu 14.04)