# No Screens found on boot: xserver initial setup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xorg, lenovo

Setup: I am a relatively new linux user but I decided to dual boot my new laptop with windows 8.1 and ubuntu. I created a bootable USB using Pen Drive linux installer (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) (12.10) and put a clean install on a separate partition that I created on my main HDD. Now when I boot from Grub it just goes to a black screen.

Hardware: Lenovo Y410p - intel core i7 and an nvidia card. I don't really care about getting the nvidia card working, I've been focused on just getting integrated graphics going.

What I've tried: for the most part I have been using suggestions from this article (http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842). So I have tried `nomodeset`, `i915.modeset=0` and various others. Most simply boot to a black screen. If I include `nomodeset` and `grub_gfxmode=1024x768x16` I get dropped to a command line, If I use the native resolution of the monitor I get a black screen. From the command line I took a look at my Xorg.0.log and a snippet is below, I can include the full version if you think it will help but this appears to be where it goes awry.

```
    [    23.409] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
    [    23.409] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
    [    23.409] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
    [    23.410] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
    [    23.410] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
    [    23.410] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
    [    23.410] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
    [    23.449] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.449]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 2.21.6
    [    23.449]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    23.449]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
    [    23.449] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
    [    23.449] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
    [    23.463] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.463]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 2.3.2
    [    23.463]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    23.463]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
    [    23.463] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
    [    23.463] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
    [    23.473] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.473]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 0.7.0
    [    23.473]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    23.473]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
    [    23.473] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
    [    23.473] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
    [    23.480] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.480]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 0.4.3
    [    23.480]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    23.480]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
    [    23.480] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
        i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
        E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
        965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
        4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
        Sandybridge Desktop (GT1), Sandybridge Desktop (GT2),
        Sandybridge Desktop (GT2+), Sandybridge Mobile (GT1),
        Sandybridge Mobile (GT2), Sandybridge Mobile (GT2+),
        Sandybridge Server, Ivybridge Mobile (GT1), Ivybridge Mobile (GT2),
        Ivybridge Desktop (GT1), Ivybridge Desktop (GT2), Ivybridge Server,
        Ivybridge Server (GT2), HD Graphics, HD Graphics 4600,
        Haswell Desktop (GT3), HD Graphics, HD Graphics 4600,
        Haswell Mobile (GT3), HD Graphics, HD Graphics P4600/P4700,
        Haswell Server (GT3), Haswell (GT1), Haswell (GT2), Haswell (GT3),
        HD Graphics, Haswell (GT2), Haswell (GT3), Haswell SDV Desktop (GT1),
        Haswell SDV Desktop (GT2), Haswell SDV Desktop (GT3),
        Haswell SDV Mobile (GT1), Haswell SDV Mobile (GT2),
        Haswell SDV Mobile (GT3), Haswell SDV Server (GT1),
        Haswell SDV Server (GT2), Haswell SDV Server (GT3),
        Haswell SDV (GT1), Haswell SDV (GT2), Haswell SDV (GT3),
        Haswell SDV (GT1), Haswell SDV (GT2), Haswell SDV (GT3),
        Haswell ULT Desktop (GT1), Haswell ULT Desktop (GT2),
        Iris(TM) Graphics 5100, HD Graphics, HD Graphics 4400,
        HD Graphics 5000, Haswell ULT Server (GT1), Haswell ULT Server (GT2),
        Iris(TM) Graphics 5100, Haswell ULT (GT1), Haswell ULT (GT2),
        Iris(TM) Graphics 5100, HD Graphics, HD Graphics 4200,
        Iris(TM) Graphics 5100, Haswell CRW Desktop (GT1), HD Graphics 4600,
        Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200, Haswell CRW Mobile (GT1),
        HD Graphics 4600, Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200,
        Haswell CRW Server (GT1), Haswell CRW Server (GT2),
        Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200, Haswell CRW (GT1), Haswell CRW (GT2),
            Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200, Haswell CRW (GT1), Haswell CRW (GT2),
        Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200, ValleyView PO board
    [    23.480] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
    [    23.480] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
    [    23.480] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
    [    23.480] (++) using VT number 7

    [    23.481] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
    [    23.481] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
    [    23.481] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
    [    23.481] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
    [    23.481] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
    [    23.482] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
    [    23.488] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.488]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 0.0.2
    [    23.489]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
    [    23.489] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
    [    23.489] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
    [    23.489] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
    [    23.501] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.501]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 1.1.0
    [    23.501]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
    [    23.501] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
    [    23.501] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
    [    23.501] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
    [    23.516] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.516]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 1.0.0
    [    23.516]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
    [    23.516] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
    [    23.516] (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range
    [    23.516] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
    [    23.516] (II) UnloadSubModule: "int10"
    [    23.516] (II) Unloading int10
    [    23.516] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vbe"
    [    23.516] (II) Unloading vbe
    [    23.516] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
    [    23.516] 
    Fatal server error:
    [    23.516] no screens found
    [    23.516] (EE) 
    Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
     for help. 
    [    23.516] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for         additional information.
    [    23.516] (EE) 
    [    23.524] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance. Any other information you need feel free to ask and I'll add it.

Comment: Similar but more closely related to the one in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: This worked for me since I was able to drop into a command line by modifying the grub2 command: http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/

Also anyone looking for Y410p linux setup help this article was very helpful and I wish I saw it from the very beginning. If you're stuck on the black screen this should point you in the right direction: [Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Y500](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272570/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-y500)