# Has anyone successfully installed ubuntu on a Lenovo Y410P

Tags: 13.10, lenovo, system-installation

I see lots of posts on here about folks having major issues with installing Ubuntu on a Lenovo Y410P. Has anyone successfully installed Ubuntu with no major issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have! I decided to go ahead and do it today before waiting on an answer to this question.

I used the top answer to this post: [Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Y500](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272570/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-y500).

It's for a Y500 but it applies to the Y410P.

Comment: Yeah, I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 on Y410p successfully last December. What problems do you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I succeeded in installing 13.10, there were some issues with dual-booting with Windows 8 but grub was able to fix it once I can boot into Ubuntu.
I am going to upgrade my 13.10 to 14.04 now. Hope it works out for me!

Answer (score 0):

I've been successful with [Kubuntu 14.04.4 LTS](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/) installation in dual boot configuration as of 29 Feb 2016 with nothing more than a 2 GB USB stick that was turned into bootable Kubuntu Live/Install medium using '[UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)'