# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo Y410p

Tags: dual-boot

I'm thinking of buying this computer and doing a dual boot with Linux and Windows 8. In all of the forums that I have read I found out that its hard to do.
If anyone can please tell how to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Y410P I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html this will help u..

Answer (score 0):

Here are some posts where people confirmed they have installed Ubuntu on this machine.

- [Has anyone successfully installed ubuntu on a Lenovo Y410P](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433792/has-anyone-successfully-installed-ubuntu-on-a-lenovo-y410p)
- [Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Y500](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272570/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-y500)

There are no big issues can be seen so far, so it's recommended to be aware of Dual Boot approaches and follow these threads generally:

- [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
- [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)
- [Installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399441/installing-ubuntu-13-10-alongside-windows-8-1)
- [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)
- [Why don't I have the option ''Install Ubuntu alongside with them''](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69481/why-dont-i-have-the-option-install-ubuntu-alongside-with-them)
- [Ubuntu install and dual Boot with Windows 8 UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193103/ubuntu-install-and-dual-boot-with-windows-8-uefi)
- [Ubuntu 13.10 installer/live fails to boot from DVD/USB on UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385159/ubuntu-13-10-installer-live-fails-to-boot-from-dvd-usb-on-uefi)
- [Install Ubuntu next to Windows 8 (UEFI dual boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236787/install-ubuntu-next-to-windows-8-uefi-dual-boot)
- [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)
- [Windows 8 deletes GRUB when booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447201/windows-8-deletes-grub-when-booting)

Answer (score 0):

I use lenovo y 580
Installing is pretty same as other laptops just get the iso file 
burn it on a pendrive press esc/f2/f9/f12 whichever gives the boot menu
make the usb as the top option using f5 and reboot it.