# Ubuntu 15.04 not loading after clean installation (hangs at "GRUB loading.")

Tags: grub2, nvidia, lenovo

I bought a new Laptop. **Lenovo Y500** with the Intel Quad and GT650 SLI configuration. *(maybe this is important)*

I set the whole thing up to load Legacy BIOS primary. As usual I installed on the HDD Windows. In parallel, I installed Ubuntu on the internal mSATA 16GB SSD. Creating only 2 partitions, root and swap, both in the SSD. Also the bootloader is placed on the SSD, so I manually decide on every boot which drive and for that which OS should be loaded.

After the installation Ubuntu keeps only loading a black screen. When I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while staring, I get a `GRUB loading.` and absolutely nothing more. I cannot even switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1/2/3</kbd>... to any console. Odd thing is that Ubuntu runs fine, when I start it in live-mode directly from the USB-drive.

I'm kinda clueless how to solve this problem, cause I'm not that "pro" with Linux, but like to do little works with it. Just tried to install 15.04, the "beta" 15.10 and for variety a Mint distro with Cinnamon. All leading to the same problem.

Comment: I would suggest that the issue here is the same as in the question:- http://askubuntu.com/questions/272570/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-y500 which has a very detailed answer.

Comment: I also found this question and tried to track the solution.
Unfortunately it doesn't help.
I tried to change the `"set gfxmode"` to `"1920x1080"` but I'm lost with the insertion of `"nomodeset=1"` option **after** installation. There is only said *"do the same as in step 3"*, but of course there is no "Install Ubuntu" entry within the config file, *after* you installed Ubuntu.

Comment: I noticed one more strange thing:
While installation Ubuntu keeps convertig the SSD to GPT. 
Isn't GRUB unable to run on a GPT drive?

Comment: Drives larger than 2.2T require GPT, and UEFI boot is also usually GPT, so GRUB is quite capable in that regard....

Comment: Ok, so this is not the failure. I already tried to replace all `quiet splash` with `nomodeset=1` and as I already got `set gfxmode=1920x1080` in my grub.cfg now I should get a picture, but it's still black and still no console available. Also tried to run the "Grub Repair Tool", which re-installed GRUB on the SSD, but it doesn't help, too.