# Unable to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo YOGA 710

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, lenovo

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 since the last two days on dualboot with windows 10 on a seperate partition.
At first, it got installed but wouldn't always boot on and got stuck on the bootscreen animation and would boot only 1 out of every 4 or 5 times I tried to boot it up.
After that, I wen to windows and deleted that partition and tried to install ubuntu 14.04.
It installed but didn't show the wifi networks so I removed that too and now I'm unable to install any version, every time I boot into the usb drive, it gets frozen at the ubuntu boot screen and doesn't proceed to the setup.
My Windows is working perfectly smooth.
Device config:
Intel core i7 skylake
8G ram
256 ssd
Used both rufus and Universal usb installer for creating the live USB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Y500](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272570/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-y500)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Ubuntu working pretty well on my laptop. It's the 15.6 inch version with an i7 and a GeForce 940M(X).

It was actually quite easy to get running. I installed it in the standard way. However, booting can be a bit of an issue.

What causes the boot failure on these laptops is ACPI. You need to either disable it or set it to noirq mode. If you disable it, you lose power controls.

If you disable ACPI, you can get back most of its functionality by enabling APM, the older ancestor for ACPI.

Anyhow, how do you do this? When you are at the GRUB boot screen, press `e`, taking you to the advanced settings.
In the line with the linux boot flags, throw in `acpi=off apm=1` or `acpi=noirq`.

That should allow you to boot.

In order to make the changes permanent, edit: `/etc/default/grub` as root. Set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to the option(s) you used that worked. Save that file.

Now, run `sudo update-grub` in order to regenerate the GRUB configuration files.

You should be able to successfully (re)boot.

EDIT: Editing the grub configuration file in `/boot/...` is a very bad idea because it's automatically generated and will be overwritten next time update-grub works (updating the kernel, etc.). Instead, you update the local Grub configuration file and use update-grub to regenerate the proper configuration file for you.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer because it suggests `acpi=noirq` as well as `acpi=off`.

Many answers in various forums suggest `acpi=off`; that at least gets past the kernel panic on boot! But in this mode:

* I found my laptop still on and hot in my bag;
* no battery symbol in the status bar;
* `lscpu` said I had only 1 CPU;
* choosing 'shutdown' from the menu just hangs.

So...not a long term solution.

But changing `acpi=off` to `acpi=noirq` still boots, gets a battery icon (and menus and power management), `lscpu` reports 4 CPUs, and 'shutdown' works.

Thanks Devyash!

Comment: My pleasure. However, I'm currently working on figuring out how to not use acpi=noirq because that makes it impossible for the NVidia driver (or nouveau) to find the 940MX.

Comment: That would be great. My setup has been very stable for a few days now,  thanks to your suggestion. Prior to using `acpi=noirq` I was getting all sorts of issues: processes taking all the CPU; the trackpad 'grabbing' windows and moving them when I wasn't trying to; repeated keystrokes, and so on. One thing that is intriguing is that when I ran the Ubuntu demo mode from a USB stick the touch screen worked. I haven't had time to take a look at the boot setup on the USB stick to see how it differs, though...

Comment: Actually my touch screen used to work before. It stopped working for some random reason I don't know about!

Comment: Thanks, it does boot up now but the touchscreen doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

After further tinkering with my laptop, I have solved most instabilities. I upgraded to the latest (bleeding edge) kernel build, though that might be unnecessary. Then I installed the latest NVidia drivers. As of writing this, version 375 is installed.

After the installation of the driver, I installed bumblebee because the graphics chipset is optimus enabled.

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

Thereafter, I blacklisted the `i2c_hid` driver because that was causing boot issues.

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add in the following line at the end

```
blacklist i2c_hid
```

Press `[:]` then type `wq`, then press `[enter]`
Run the following commands to make your changes permanent

```
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot and you should be up and running without using any ACPI flags, such as `acpi=noirq`

If there are any problems this causes, let me know. I've certainly left out steps in this procedure somewhere, so the fix is probably something I already know. But please try to provide a description of the error.

Comment: Install the driver from the NVidia website. The ones available via apt-get break way too easily for this laptop build :/

Comment: Any way to get the touchscreen back to work?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box I had no such luck with a dual boot as well. UEFI ruins all the fun... though Im sure it possible, My knowledge is not adequate. Although I am now running on a dual boot. I created my Win10 usb boot disk, then made a Win10 recovery USB and single boot installed Ubuntu Gnome. No touch screen support that i could figure out. Frustrated I reinstalled Win10 in Legacy by accident... and well after recovering with the recovery usb Id made prior I had no problem creating up the partitions and installing Ubuntu. Still no touch screen support. I guess I'll have to wait for that. But if you feel bold I'd say go for it! It worked for me! Sloppy but it worked!