# Ubuntu Slow Boot on Lenovo Yoga 700

Tags: boot, lenovo

I have an Lenovo Yoga 700 laptop and it has both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. My problem is it starts Windows 10 normally but lately it has a problem with booting Ubuntu.

I used the `dmesg` command to see what delays. Apparently I found the problem, but unfortunately I couldn't find the solution. I am guessing it has something to do with touchpad/touchscreen. I have found the same problem on some other sites but no solution. Two consecutive lines from `dmesg`:

```
[8.053972] i2c_hid i2c-ITE8396:00: error in i2c_hid_init_report size:19 / ret_size:18
[97.054224] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

How can I eliminate these 89 seconds of delay?

Comment: Try this one, it worked on 710 http://askubuntu.com/a/861110/589698

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem on my yoga 710.

[This answer helped](https://askubuntu.com/a/861110/589698">https://askubuntu.com/a/861110/589698)

Setting `acpi=1` & `apm1` as [boot parameters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) may help, but looking at your `dmesg` I think all that's needed is to blacklist `i2c_hid`.

To do this, create a file

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-i2c_hid.conf
```

enter this text

```
blacklist i2c_hid
```

Save, exit, and reboot.